# How to correctly instantiate object from the class you are testing in JUnit 5 in a before hook?

Tags: java, object, testing, junit, scope

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    Airport airport = new Airport();
}
@Test
public void has_storage(){
    ArrayList<String> airport_storage;
    airport_storage = new ArrayList<String>();
    airport_storage.add("plane");
    ArrayList<String> actual_storage = airport.storage();
```

I am trying to test my airport class with the class AirportTest. Similar to RSpec/Jasmine and a few other testing frameworks I have used I want to make sure I get a new instance of the object for each test. Although I have read that instance variables will not persist across tests anyway in JUnit, so this may not be necessary. Why am I getting an error that the compiler cannot resolve symbol airport? How to correctly declare and initialise the instance of airport so that is in the scope of each @Test?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `airport` variable is only known inside the `setUp` block. As the error said, it doesn't know what variable you're talking about.

To fix it, you need to declare `airport` on the class level, as a member variable:

```
public class MyTest{
     private Airport airport; // declare as a private class member

     @Before
     public void setUp() {
         airport = new Airport(); // instantiate it before every test
     }

     @Test
     public void has_storage(){
         ArrayList<String> airport_storage;
         airport_storage = new ArrayList<String>();
         airport_storage.add("plane");
         ArrayList<String> actual_storage = airport.storage(); // use it without problems
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I figured it was poor knowledge of scope in Java that was letting me down!

Comment: Sorry, I have changed my code to this:
    private Airport airport;
    //@Before
    public void setUp() {
        airport = new Airport();
    }
    //@Test
    public void has_storage(){
        ArrayList<String> test_storage = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> actual_storage = airport.storage();

Now giving me a null pointer exception where I am calling .storage, on airport, I don't understand why this is? I understand a null pointer exception comes from trying to access a class that has not been instantiated?

Comment: @rb20 can you ensure that `setUp` is really called? Does the logic inside `storage()` depend on other objects, which might be null?

Comment: Hi Lino, thanks again for the response, I tried some debugging through printing and it appear BeforeEach fixes my problem, seems like I need to read up on the subtle difference between Before and BeforeEach in jUnit!

Answer (score 0):

@Before is a Junit 4 annotation
In Junit 5 you have @BeforeAll and @BeforeEach.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations